# Numerical vs. categorical vars: Why 100% correlation for categorical variable with high cardinality?

Tags: python, statistics, data-science, correlation, exploratory-data-analysis

I am new to data science and trying to get a grip on exploratory data analysis. My goal is to get a correlation matrix between all the variables. For numerical variables I use Pearson's R, for categorical variables I use the corrected Cramer's V. The issue now is to get a meaningful correlation between categorical and numerical variables. For that I use the correlation ratio, as outlined [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-search-for-categorical-correlation-a1cf7f1888c9). The issue with that is that categorical variables with high cardinality show a high correlation no matter what:

[correlation matrix cat vs. num](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SRjN.png)

This seems nonsensical, since this would practically show the cardinality of the the categorical variable instead of the correlation to the numerical variable. The question is: how to deal with the issue in order to get a meaningful correlation.

The Python code below shows how I implemented the correlation ratio:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], 'num3': [6,3,3,9,6,9,9,3,6,3,6,9],
    'cat2': [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1], 'cat3': [0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2],
    'cat6': [0,4,8,2,6,10,0,4,8,2,6,10], 'cat12': [0,7,2,9,4,11,6,1,8,3,10,5],
})
cat_cols, num_cols = ['cat2','cat3','cat6','cat12'], ['id','num3']

def corr_ratio(cats, nums):
    avgtotal = nums.mean()
    elements_avg, elements_count = np.zeros(len(cats.index)), np.zeros(len(cats.index))
    cu = cats.unique()
    for i in range(cu.size):
        cn = cu[i]
        filt = cats == cn
        elements_count[i] = filt.sum()
        elements_avg[i] = nums[filt].mean(axis=0)
    numerator = np.sum(np.multiply(elements_count, np.power(np.subtract(elements_avg, avgtotal), 2)))
    denominator = np.sum(np.power(np.subtract(nums, avgtotal), 2))  # total variance
    return 0.0 if numerator == 0 else np.sqrt(numerator / denominator)

rows = []
for cat in cat_cols:
    col = []
    for num in num_cols:
        col.append(round(corr_ratio(train[cat], train[num]), 2))
    rows.append(col)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(rows), columns=num_cols, index=cat_cols)
sns.heatmap(df)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be because I think you are visualising something more related to chi-2 in your seaborn plot. Cramer's V is a number derived from chi-2 but not equivalent. So it means you could have a high value for a specific cell but a more relevant value for Cramer's V. I'm not even sure it makes sense to compare raw modalities values because they could be on a totally different order of magnitude.

[Chi 2 formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KHXP.png)
[Cramer's V formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmjWt.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, there is another method called **Theil’s U**. How about trying this out and see if the same problem will occur?

You can use this:
num_cols: `your_df.select_dtypes(include=['number']).columns.to_list()` 
cat_target_cols: `your_df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns.to_list()`

```
corr_df = pd.DataFrame(associations(dataset=your_df, numerical_columns=num_cols, nom_nom_assoc='theil', figsize=(20, 20), nominal_columns=cat_target_cols).get('corr'))
```

Comment: As far as I know Theil's U is for measuring the correlation between two categorical variables, similar to Cramer's V, and the difference between these two is, that Theil's U is asymmetric.

Comment: I see. Sorry for not being able to help you. As I am also facing difficulties in doing correlation analysis. I am not sure whether this `dython` library package is reliable enough or not to tell the correlation between each variable in my dataset. 

How I used this library is shown in the above answer. Not sure it is correct?

Comment: Yes, I have experimented with the `dython` package, too. Its default settings are Pearson's R  for numerical/numerical, Cramer's V for categorical/categorical, and the poor correlation ration. Interestingly these can be replaced by some custom function.

Comment: I see. U mean we can customize it by passing in some parameters into the `associations()` function?

Comment: Yes, specify the kwarg like this  `associations(nom_num_assoc=custom_function)` and you define the `custom_function()` in your code. If you don't specify this kwarg, dython would use the correlation_ratio by default.

Comment: Is there any alternative way to calculate the correlation between categorical data and numerical data aside from correlation ratio?

Comment: Not that I know of, so I created one that makes sense to me: https://www.kaggle.com/code/taqseorangpun/correlation-categorical-continuous-vs-cardinality

Comment: Wao, you are awesome!!!